# Choosing an appropriate sequence in order to achieve a desirable limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let two sequences $\;{\varepsilon}_n\;,x_n\;$ such that $\;{\varepsilon}_n \to 0^{+}\;$ and $\;x_n \to +\infty\;$ as $\;n \to +\infty\;$. **I wonder if I could choose $\;x_n\;$ in such a way that**

> $\;\frac {{\pi}^2}{4} + \frac
>  {{\pi}^2}{8}(x_n-1+{\varepsilon}_n){\cos}^2 (\frac {\pi}{2}
>  (1-{\varepsilon_n})) \to \frac {{\pi}^2}{4}\;$

*My attempt:*

It is sufficient to show that $\;(x_n-1+{\varepsilon}_n){\cos}^2 (\frac {\pi}{2} (1-{\varepsilon_n})) \to 0\;$ but according to the initial assumptions letting $\;n \to +\infty\;$ I get $\;(+\infty -1 +0){\cos}^2 (\frac {\pi}{2} (1-0))=(+\infty)\times 0\;$ which is undefined.

**Questions:**

How can I overcome this problem? Is it possible at first place ? How would the choice of $\;x_n\;$ affect the above limit, since $\;x_n \to +\infty\;$?

Any help would be valuable! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are given the sequence $\{\varepsilon_n\}$ and are allowed to choose the sequence $\{x_n\}$.

Note that $\cos(\frac\pi2(1-t)) \sim \frac{\pi t}2$ when $t$ is small (this is just a tangent line approximation). If you choose $x_n = 1/\varepsilon_n$, you should then be able to show that $(x_n-1+\varepsilon_n)\cos^2 (\frac {\pi}{2} (1-\varepsilon_n)) \to 0$.